# Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Tags: php, sql, excel, sqlsrv

I am a bit new to programming, I have a query in PHP with SQLSRV but when exporting to Excel does not give me the result, I throw the error

> Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows () Expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

this is the code, the SQL query itself executes in SQL Server, but here the Excel gives me that error, and internet search and search but can not find an answer, this is the code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Movimientos Cancelados del Mes.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$server = "server";
$info = array("Database"=>"DB","UID"=>"USR","PWD"=>"" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $info);
$param = array('ReturnDatesAsStrings'=> true);
$opt = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);

$per = $_GET["periodo"];
$eje = $_GET["ejercicio"];
$mov = 'Movimiento';
$est = 'Estatus';
$cli = 'Cliente';
$rfc = 'RFC';
$tot = 'Total';
$fec = 'Fecha Timbrado';
$uuid = 'UUID';
$cert = 'Certificado SAT';
$sql = "select v.MovID as '$mov',v.Estatus as '$est',v.Cliente as '$cli',cte.rfc as '$rfc',(v.Importe+v.Impuestos)as '$tot', c.FechaTmibrado as '$fec', c.UUID as '$uuid',c.noCertificadoSAT as '$cert'
from Venta V join CFD c on v.MovID = c.MovID join cte on v.cliente = cte.cliente 
where V.Estatus = 'Cancelado' and c.Periodo = '$per' and c.Ejercicio = '$eje' and  c.Empresa = 'MGJ' 
order by FechaEmision";

$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$campos = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);

$i = 0;

echo "<table border=''><tr>";
echo "<th>$mov</th>";
echo "<th>$est</th>";
echo "<th>$cli</th>";
echo "<th>$rfc</th>";
echo "<th>$tot</th>";
echo "<th>$uuid</th>";
echo "<th>$cert</th>";

while ($i<$campos) {
    echo "<td>".sqlsrv_get_field($query,$i);
    echo "</td>";
    $i++;
}
    echo "</tr>";
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j=0; $j < $campos; $j++) { 
        echo "<td>".$row[$j]."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
   sqlsrv_close( $conn);
print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true);
?>
```

Comment: Your `$query` failed, run check for errors. I'm also not clear what `excel` has to do with this, does Excel have a driver that can execute PHP? You also are open to SQL injections.

Comment: It also gives you a line number on that error. Would you like to give us a bit of a clue as to which line of your code is erroring, ro shall we just look at it all until we manually compile it in our heads

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php you'll see that when you're running your query it's failing which means that $query is FALSE; which in turn causes the error when you try to pass a bool instead of a resource.

May I suggest that you look into using PDO instead?

Comment: Been a while since I sqlservered but I would take a guess that `'$mov'` should be just `$mov` etc etc etc

Comment: can you please check if is there anything wrong with columnnames, `sqlsrv_errors()`

Comment: @chris85 My query runs perfectly in SQL, if I print on screen the result shows me what (unformatted) but I want to download to Excel so they can manipulate the information.

Comment: @RicardoRomero Just an idea... But are you sure that your server name is 'server'? Shouldn't you be connecting to 'localhost'?  You may very well have named your server 'server' but it's just not something I'd normally do.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the error line that's shown is 30

Comment: Okay, so the Excel information is not needed here. Try to keep the issue as simple as possible (as little information needed to reproduce the error).

Comment: @Rawrskyes Change the information brother, this is not a problem, the file is correct.

Comment: @RicardoRomero Yes I know, that comment was more for future reference

Comment: @VuralAcar I realized that the name of one of the columns was misspelled, now if you run the query but Excel to download this blank...

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for the observation

Comment: Can you please rephrase `now if you run the query but Excel to download this blank`? If you just run the query without Excel involvement does it work?

Comment: @chris85 It's hard for me not to mention Excel because what I want is to download it in Excel and it's what I have right now, I know I just said yes printed on screen the result, but as I said initially, the programming is new for me, I do not know much about programming ...

Comment: The question you asked about though is `Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows` which you have resolved, so you are asking a different question here. I'm not an Excel user so I can't help you with this. The PHP execution works so it is something with the Excel interaction.

Comment: @chris85 If i run query on SQL there's no problem, now the problem is the Excel exporting thanks to VuralAcar for the observation

Comment: Yes @chris85, so thanks a lot everyone that commented the post, you just opened my eyes

Answer (score 0):

> Warning: sqlsrv_num_rows () Expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

It means, your query does not return a resource object because the query failed to compile or run.

To see why this happens, you can use `sqlsrv_errors()`

```
if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
    foreach( $errors as $error ) {
        echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
        echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
        echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: And why would that be may I ask, on behalf of the OP

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am trying to figure it out

Comment: _your query does not return a resource object_ because the query failed to compile or run, would do

Comment: This would be better suited as a comment then an answer.

Comment: @chris85 Yes that as well. Except it already is a comment, _yours in fact_ So a delete woudl be my advice

Comment: Well, then there is no answer for this question. We cannot validate the column names.

Comment: You're posting in the `answer` section though. If you think `there is no answer for this question` then you shouldn't post an answer.

Comment: I am saying this, because you guys think that this is not an answer. I am showing how to check the query for errors. Now OP should test and check for the errors.